# How do I get a list of files modified between two arbitrary changesets?

Tags: mercurial

My only guess is something horrible like this:

```
# files where something has been added
hg diff -r AA -r BB|grep -- +++|cut -f1|cut -d/ -f2- >/tmp/ka

# files where something has been removed
hg diff -r AA -r BB|grep -- ---|cut -f1|cut -d/ -f2- >>/tmp/ka

# filtering out "dev/null": it appears when a file is added or removed from the repository
sort -u /tmp/ka |grep -v dev/null
```

What I need is the files modified between changeset AA and changeset BB. Something like `hg diff -r AA -r BB` but file names only, instead of a whole diff.

Maybe there's a mercurial command I didn't notice?  The changesets I want to examine are not consecutive, otherwise I could have just used `hg status`.

---

**NOT** the modified files of a single changeset.

---

edit: I need to do this because I'm working with some programmers from the Bronze Age who don't understand what a .diff is, please bear with me...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789442/mercurial-all-files-that-changed-in-a-changeset, although this question is a more general one IMO.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`hg diff -r 182 -r 193 --stat`

or

`hg status --rev 182:193`

Comment: `--rev` and `-r` behave the same on my system...was that a bug in 2012?

Comment: Seems like it's fixed now, yes.

Answer (score 8):

The basic command to look for when you want to know something about file status is `hg status`. The status command is the **file name** oriented command and you want to know some file names.

When you run it as

```
$ hg status
```

then it compares the working copy state with the working copy parent revision (`.`). But if you run it as

```
$ hg status --rev AA:BB
```

then it will show files modified between `AA` and `BB`! No need for grepping, cutting, sorting or templates.

(I've explained this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564309/110204), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173380/110204), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793664/110204), please see those questions and answers for more tips.)

Comment: Doesn't work with -r because " -r --removed             show only removed files" - that's a hard UI fail.

Comment: @asaddude: ups! Sorry about that, I've fixed it to use `--rev` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one. Diff-based**

```
>hg diff -r 3 -r 4 --stat
 comments.php  |  14 +++-----------
 functions.php |  15 +++++++++++++--
 header.php    |   2 +-
 readme.txt    |  17 ++++++++++++++---
 sidebar.php   |  43 ++++---------------------------------------
 style.css     |  18 ++++++++++++------
 6 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 62 deletions(-)
```

you can get changed files by grepping on "|" char, or (better and nicer approach from my POV) pipe output to gawk, which, for **record with exactly 4 fields**, print $1

**Solution two. Log + templating + revsets**

```
>hg log -r "3::4" --template "{file_mods}\n"
footer.php functions.php header.php search.php style.css
comments.php functions.php header.php readme.txt sidebar.php style.css
```

convert to list, remove (possible) duplicates I'll leave for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to `hg stat` **in Tortoise Workbench**.

---

**The simplest / most built-in way is**:

- In the main listing of revisions, click/select the two that you want to compare
- Right click one of them
- From the context menu, select "Visual Diff..."

This will produce a window similar to the following example:

[image]

(Then just click the [X]).

This screen may have limited use however... for instance you can't readily export it, other than taking a screenshot. You can copy/paste the text of individual lines one-by-one, however.

---

An alternate way **which produces a useful text output** is to automate the use of `hg stat` right from THG Workbench, by adding a custom tool.

- File menu > Settings
- Global settings tab
- Leftnav > Tools section
- [New Tool...]
- Enter details as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

- Click OK
- Then make sure to add the "filecomp" tool to at least one of the GUI locations in the dropdown
- Restart THG

Now when you run that tool, you'll automatically get the results in the log pane. You can select a single or multiple changesets and it will compare them accordingly.

Note - alternately you can configure this in the settings file by adding:

```
[tortoisehg-tools]
filecomp.command = hg stat --rev {REVID}
filecomp.enable = istrue
filecomp.label = FILECOMP
filecomp.showoutput = True
```

The macro `{REVID}` will expand to text like `33a6bd983eab` if you selected one changeset in the list, or like `33a6bd983eab+a41898ae15c4`if you selected two, etc.

In this method *you can actually select > 2 changesets* and it will report on the combined differences among them.

---

Also just to note there is an alternate syntax for `stat` to get a listing of what file differences exist between any two changesets which I don't think was mentioned in the other answers:

```
hg stat --rev A --rev B
```

where `A` and `B` are the changeset IDs (which look like `1c845eefe22e`).

(You could also use the revision number like 12345 in place of the changeset ID, but be aware that these are not permanent values unlike the IDs).

`A` and `B` could be on any two branches, or the same branch, it doesn't matter, as long as both exist in the local clone you are working with.