# Mercurial Reports for documenting changsets?

Tags: mercurial, report

Is there a way report the differences between changesets and branches?

For example:  What files changed between the development branch and the testing branch or between changeset 1 and 2?  This information is used in a software version description for an inventory of software.  Thanks

I am new to Mercurial so have limited knowledge.  We use Tortoise HG and I see no reportig functions at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial: list "hg diff" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874643/mercurial-list-hg-diff-files)

Comment: FYI I added an answer to another question specifically to suggest ways of doing this in THG: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57080623/3195477

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
hg diff -r changeSet1:changeSet2
```

or  if you want to see list of files that changes:

```
hg status -r changeSet1:changeSet2
```

Comment: The second one is the one I think I need since I am only looking for the files that change.  Can you do this for multiple change sets?  Say I have 5 changesets since my last stable baseline and I want to see all files changed to got into my current stable baseline at changeset5 ... would it be hg status -r changeset1:Changeset2:changeset3:changeset4:Changeset5?

Comment: I think you can do it like this: 'hg status -r changeSet1:changeSet5'.
This should print all the files that changed from changeSet5 up to changeSet1.